# Copy specific cells from selected rows and paste specified column other workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I have a floating button which when I have selected some rows and presses the button I want some specified cells from the selected rows to be copied and then pasted into a other workbook which opens when button is pressed.

For example the value in Column A rows 2-3 is selected and when I press the button I want the values in column A from the selected rows to be copied to column B from start of row 2. The values in column E to be copied to column F etc.

I have found following code but I can't find out how to modify the code to specify what cells to copy to where.

Anyone out there to give me some hints?

```
Sub CopyCells()
    Dim Rng As Range
    For Each Rng In Selection.Areas
    Union(Rng.Resize(, 6), Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, 1)).Copy Sheets("Blad2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 5)
    Next Rng
    Worksheets("Blad2").Activate
End Sub
```

New code:

```
Public Sub CopyCells()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet 'define source sheet
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim wsDest As Worksheet 'define destination sheet
    Dim wbDest As Workbook 'define destination workbook
    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Test.xlsx")
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim DestRow As Long
    DestRow = 2 'start in row 2 in destination sheet

    Dim Rng As Range
    For Each Rng In Selection.Areas
         Rng.Resize(, 1).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "B") 'copy A to B
         Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, 4).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "F") 'copy E to F
         DestRow = DestRow + Rng.Rows.Count 'move DestRow to next free row
    Next Rng
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a copy action for each column if the columns are not continous.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyAtoBandEtoF()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet 'define source sheet
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source")

    Dim wsDest As Worksheet 'define destination sheet
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination")

    Dim DestRow As Long
    DestRow = 2 'start in row 2 in destination sheet

    Dim Rng As Range
    For Each Rng In Selection.Areas
        Rng.Resize(, 1).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "B") 'copy A to B
        Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, 4).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "F") 'copy E to F
        DestRow = DestRow + Rng.Rows.Count 'move DestRow to next free row
    Next Rng
End Sub
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Trying to change destination to another Workbook but gets error 9 outside interval. (added the code in my original post).

Comment: `Workbooks("C:\Temp\Test.xlsx")` assumes that this workbook is already opened. If it is closed you must use the [Workbooks.Open method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open): `Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\Temp\Test.xlsx")`

Comment: Now it opens the Destination file but no thing is pasted.

Comment: It should work, the code is tested. It assumes that you select *full* rows in the source sheet, and that the source sheet is active when the code is run. You can debug the code by going through it step-by-step with F8 to see what happens.

Comment: If I change back to copy to sheet on the same workbook it works and copies as it should.

Comment: It should work too. a) Are you sure you selected full rows? What is the result of `Debug.Print Selection.Address` (run before the loop). b) What happens if you go through the code step-by-step? Try adding a `wsSrc.Parent.Activate: wsSrc.Activate` right before the loop.

Comment: Worked as soon as I used wsSrc.Parent.Activate: wsSrc.Activate. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: this is the only solution that can copy multiple items from multiple selected rows without a loop. it is elegant and beautiful.